# How do I make my program check whether user input is within 5,10,15,20, etc of the random integer?

Tags: python, random

```
import random

print("Pick a number from 1-50")

randomNumber = random.randint(1,50)
correct = False

while not correct:
    try:
        userInput = int(input("Insert your number here. "))
    except ValueError:
        print("That is not a Number!")
        continue
    if userInput > randomNumber:
        print("Guess lower.")
    elif userInput < randomNumber:
        print("Guess Higher.")
    else:
        print("You got it!")
        break
```

So this code currently takes the user input and says whether the user guessed the random integer, or if they should guess higher/lower. I want to edit the code to now say whether the user input is within 5,10,15, etc of the random integer.

So if the random integer was 30, and the user inputs 20, the program would say something like "You are within 10; guess higher."

Any advice? I'm extremely new to python, so please respond with more simple methods if possible.

Thanks.

PS: Oh, preferably without the use of modules, mainly because I'm still learning.

Comment: By the way, it would be clearer to just write `while True:`.  You never reset the `correct` variable, and the way it's currently written it makes the reader think that `correct` will be reset during the `while` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does what you want, and it cuts down on the if chains a little:

```
import random

print("Pick a number from 1-50")

randomNumber = random.randint(1,50)
correct = False

while not correct:
    try:
        userInput = int(input("Insert your number here. "))
    except ValueError:
        print("That is not a Number!")
        continue
    if randomNumber == userInput: # Let's check this first!
        print ("YOU WIN!!!")
        break # We use break b/c changing correct would still run rest of loop

    acceptable_ranges = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 25, 40, 45, 50]
    guess_error = userInput - randomNumber
    i = 0
    while abs(guess_error) > acceptable_ranges[i]: # see how close they are
        i += 1
    if guess_error < 0: # let's figure out where they need to go
        next_guess_direction = "higher"
    else:
        next_guess_direction = "lower"

    print (("You are within %i: Please guess %s")
           %(acceptable_ranges[i], next_guess_direction))
```

Let's look. at the last `if` statement a little further and the final `print` line.  We are checking to see if `guess_error`, defined above (line 15) `guess_error = userInput - randomNumber` is less than 0 (negative).  If it is less than zero, then we make the variable `next_guess_direction` equal to the string "higher," because the next guess needs to be larger than the last one (`randomNumber` was larger than `userInput`.  If `guess_error` is not negative, then it is positive, because we already eliminated the we eliminate the possibility of 0 using:

```
    if randomNumber == userInput: # Let's check this first!
        print ("YOU WIN!!!")
```

So, if guess_error is positive, we know that `userInput` was larger than `randomNumber` and we set `next_guess_direction` equal to the string "lower."  Finally, we print out everything that we have found:

```
    print (("You are within %i: Please guess %s")
           %(acceptable_ranges[i], next_guess_direction))
```

I am using an older version of formatting where `%i` and `%s` are placeholders for integer and string, respectively.  I then define what should be formatted there using `%(acceptable_ranges[i], next_guess_direction)`, which simply means to put `acceptable_ranges[i]` in for the integer and `next_guess_direction` in for the string.  Keep in mind, we found `i` in `acceptable_ranges[i]` right above the if statement.

I know that is all long, but I did not know how much detail you needed!

Comment: I have updated my answer with a fairly involved explanation.  Please let me know if you need more help with anything specifically.

Answer (score 1):

Update: I see you ask to do it without modules.  Here's a solution:

```
def ceil(xx):
    if int(xx) < xx:
        return int(xx) + 1
    else:
        return int(xx)

def generate_response(actual, guess, interval=5):
    diff_interval_units = (guess - actual) / float(interval)
    within = ceil(abs(diff_interval_units)) * interval
    response = "You are within %d" % within
    if diff_interval_units > 0:
        response += "; guess lower"
    elif diff_interval_units < 0:
        response += "; guess higher"
    return response
```

-- original answer:
You can do this with numpy's `ceil` function.

For instance:

```
import numpy as np

def generate_response(actual, guess, interval=5):
    diff_interval_units = (guess - actual) / np.float(interval)
    within = np.ceil(np.abs(diff_interval_units)) * interval
    response = "You are within %d" % within
    if diff_interval_units > 0:
        response += "; guess lower"
    elif diff_interval_units < 0:
        response += "; guess higher"
    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution using the [modulo operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#index-52):

```
import random
randomNumber = random.randint(0,100)

def guess(divisor = 5):
    while 1:
        try:
            print("Pick a number from 0-100")
            userInput = int(input("Insert your number here: "))
        except ValueError:
            print("That is not a Number!")
            continue

        delta = randomNumber - userInput

        if delta == 0:
            print("You got it!")
            return

        remainder = delta % divisor
        # this takes advantage of python truncating non-floating point numbers
        rounded_delta = (abs(delta) / divisor) * divisor + divisor * bool(remainder)

        high_or_low = 'higher' if delta > 0 else 'lower'
        print("You are within %s. Guess %s." % (rounded_delta, high_or_low))
```